# Thymeleaf Get Curent request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a web app with Thymeleaf and Spring boot. I am using Fragments and a layout ; All I need is to print the request parameter in the header.

Exemple :

- when i open localhost:8080/foo/boo , My header print  /foo/boo
- when i open localhost:8080/foo?size=5 , My header print  /foo?size=5

Is there any variable in Thymeleaf to get that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path up to the query string:

```
${#request.requestURI}
```

The query string:

```
${#request.queryString}
```

Get a specific parameter (from the query string):

```
${#request.getParameter('size')}
```

Comment: It works also with ${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()}

Comment: Why is this giving me "Access to request parameters is forbidden in this context" :/
`<a th:if="${NOT param.isEmpty()}" th:href="@{${#request.requestURI} + ${#request.queryString} + '&sort=subject'}" th:text="#{tsubject}"></a>`

Comment: Because thymleaf team decided to prevent thymleaf user to access request directly. See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html point 1.6